# ios - how do I extract a string from another string which is in JSON format?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have an NSString like this:

```
[{"comment":"I am just weighing the idea."}]
```

How do I make it into a JSON object and get the value of the comment key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iOS's `NSJSONSerialization` object to get an object graph from JSON string/data. That API expects an NSData, so first you'll need to put the string into one.

```
NSData * jsonData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray * root = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];
NSString * comment = [[root objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"comment"];
```

After processing, that root object should be an array or dictionary. In your case, it's clearly an array containing a dictionary.